# delaying read from the telnet connection

Tags: c#, telnet

I'm reading data from telnet with network stream like this :

```
string out_string = Encoding.Default.GetString(ReadFully(readStream,0));
```

note:ReadFully gets the network stream and does the trick.

my question is how can I put a delay before above line to delay reading data from "readStream" for a few seconds?

Comment: If you are trying to delay to ensure that you have received an entire (something), you would be better off buffering the contents and looking for a key (like CR/LF) and then process it rather than trying to sleep for a while.  Network retransmits can delay packets for up to 120 seconds or break packets up so you only receive parts of it, etc.  Trying to use timing isn't a good idea typically, unless you only want to have it sleep between reads you are buffering, then ignore my comment.

Comment: And if you are using sleep to trigger reads periodically, you would likely be better off using a different call that you can block on until you either receive some data, or the socket closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Thread.Sleep(8000);
string out_string = Encoding.Default.GetString(ReadFully(readStream,0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sleep the current thread as follows:

```
Thread.Sleep([Number of milliseconds]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

delays 5 seconds your operation.